Jolt Remove Entry if a key is not present
My input JSON is like below
[
  {
    "id": "112",
    "key": "value1",
    "dfsf": "dffd"
  },
  {
    "key1": "value2"
  },
  {
    "id": "113",
    "key2": "value3"
  }
]

If id is not present, I want to remove the entry itself such that my output JSON looks like
[
  {
    "id": "112",
    "key": "value1"
  },
  {
    "id": "113",
    "key2": "value3"
  }
]


You can replicate all the values from the level of id by using a @1 on the left-hand-side nested within the innermost object while filtering it by "id" which's the key of the object such as
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id": {
          "@1": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :


Much Thanks for the help @Barbaros. This works.
